# Invalid Scopes: user_location. When one click facebook login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

`Invalid Scopes: user_location. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at`

But it's valid:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_location

Answer (score 0):

I check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) request status. And saw it

> Not requested

that's why I removed `.userLocation` from `LoginManager().logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile, .email]`. It's works.

[image: screen here]